# .htaccess works fine offline but not online

Tags: linux, .htaccess

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule !\.(gif)$ c1.php [NC]
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?  whats the chmod need to be given to a .htaccess file, 755?

Answer (score 0):

The file looks fine.

Your hosting company may be preventing use of .htaccess files. You could contact them and ask about it.

The required permissions can vary depending on your server setup, but if you want to make sure that isn't the issue you could try setting them to 777 and see if that works. If it doesn't, you can rule out a permissions issue for sure. 755 really should work regardless of your server setup though.

Comment: I tried a 777 and a 755 does not work.  How do I check myself if .htaccess is prevented from usage?  This is a standalone centOS server

Comment: Sounds like your apache config is the problem then. You may need to edit your httpd.conf file. Take a look [at this](http://www.tildemark.com/enable-htaccess-on-apache/)

Comment: Also, don't forget that any changes to httpd.conf will not take effect until you restart apache (or force it to reload httpd.conf).

Comment: There must be something that I have overlooked, its not working.

Comment: To make 100% sure your .htaccess isn't working, try adding this line to your .htaccess: `deny from all`. This will prevent access to any page on your site. It's worth checking this just in case it's a problem with the rewrite module rather than .htaccess itself. Is this a clean install of apache2? In your httpd.conf, is there a line that looks like this: `AllowOverride all` within a directory section? Can you post your httpd.conf file so I can take a look? You may find the [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) helpful